# Load scipy sparse csr_matrix in c++

Tags: python, c++, numpy, sparse-matrix

I saved a scipy sparse csr matrix in a .npz file thanks to the save_sparse_csr(filename,array) given in this link:

[Save / load scipy sparse csr_matrix in portable data format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8955448/save-load-scipy-sparse-csr-matrix-in-portable-data-format)

So, I obtained an .npz archive Matrix.npz which contains data.npy, indices.npy, indptr.npy, shape.npy files.

However I am trying to load with these files the initial sparse matrix in C++. Unfortunately I am a beginner in C++ and I don't know how to do it. I found a library which reads .npz and .npy files in C++ in that link :
https://github.com/rogersce/cnpy

I loaded the four arrays mentioned above in this code:

`cnpy::NpyArray d = cnpy::npz_load("Matrix.npz","data");
  cnpy::NpyArray ind = cnpy::npz_load("Matrix.npz","indices");
  cnpy::NpyArray indptr = cnpy::npz_load("Matrix.npz","indptr"); 
  cnpy::NpyArray sh = cnpy::npz_load("Matrix.npz","shape");`

Any help? Thanks.

Comment: You'll have to find a c++ library that implements sparse matrices.  By themselves these 4 arrays aren't going to be useful.

Comment: A recent C++ sparse matrix question on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29598299/csr-matrix-matrix-multiplication