# mulitply a CSR matrix to a vector

Tags: python, matrix-multiplication

I was following this stackoverflow post [on csr matrix multiplication to a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29598299/csr-matrix-matrix-multiplication)
and Implement it in python and getting list out of range error.

Here is my code:

```
def MatrixMultiplication(data,row_ptr,col_ptr,vec):
  ResultMatrix =[]
  vec_len = len(vec)
  for i in range(0,vec_len):
    ResultMatrix.insert(i,0)
  for i in range(0,vec_len):
    start, end = row_ptr[i], row_ptr[i + 1]
    for k in range(start, end):
      ResultMatrix[i] = ResultMatrix[i]+data[k]*vec[col_ptr[k]]
  return ResultMatrix

data = [2, 4, 7, 1, 3, 2]
row_ptr =  [2,3 ,5, 5 ,6]
col_ptr = [1 ,3, 4, 0, 3, 3]
vec = [2,3, 5, 4, 2]

MatrixMultiplication(data,row_ptr,col_ptr,vec)
```

Please help me out where I am going wrong .

Output should be: [ 22 14 14 0 8]

Error :

```
IndexError: list index out of range
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-338158343473691> in <module>()
----> 1 MatrixMultiplication(data,row_ptr,col_ptr,vec)

<command-3658506804172571> in MatrixMultiplication(data, row_ptr, col_ptr, vec)
      5     ResultMatrix.insert(i,0)
      6   for i in range(0,vec_len):
----> 7     start, end = row_ptr[i], row_ptr[i + 1]
      8     for k in range(start, end):
      9       ResultMatrix[i] = ResultMatrix[i]+data[k]*vec[col_ptr[k]]

IndexError: list index out of range
```

FYI:

the last element of row_ptr  will be size of the data list

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the traceback of the error you're seeing.

Comment: @NiayeshIsky I have edited and added the error message to the question.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is pretty self-explanatory: You're trying to access `row_ptr[i + 1]` in a for loop that goes up to `vec_len`, which is the length of your list. When you've reached the last iteration of your for loop and `i = vec_len - 1`, then `i + 1 = vec_len`, which is out of the range of your list (remember, Python lists are 0-initialised).

To prevent this error, your range should only go up to `vec_len - 1` in your second for loop.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I have already done that but the answer was wrong, after changing to `(vec_len-1)` I am getting [14, 14, 0, 8, 0] as answer,  but I am supposed to get [ 22 14 14 0 8]

Comment: @dark lion Well, `[14, 14, 0, 8, 0]` is just `[22, 14, 14, 0, 8]` shifted left by one element, so that should give you a hint as to where you're going wrong.

Comment: Apparently, yes , I am trying to figure that out :)

Comment: @dark lion By the way, your first for loop can be replaced with `ResultMatrix = [0] * vec_len` because `0` is a scalar.